# frustration in netplan

Tags: networking, server, netplan

I've been scratching my head the whole day.
I have the following netplan yaml file: (with mac address & ip addresses masked out for privacy)

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      match:
        macaddress: "aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff"
      set-name: enp2s0
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [ "10.9.8.7/24" ]
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 10.9.8.8
          metric: 254
          table: 253
  vlans:
    vlan202:
      link: enp2s0
      id: 202
      addresses: [ 75.xxx.yyy.zzz/24 ]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [ 75.xxx.yyy.111, 75.75.75.75 ]
        search: [ example.org, example.com ]
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 75.xxx.yyy.100
          metric: 200
          table: 253
```

then I ran the command `netplan try`, make sure it doesn't have any errors then `netplan generate`. I then checked in /etc/systemd/network, it was empty, and I checked in /run/systemd/network, it has 2 files:

10-netplan-enp2s0.link:

```
[Match]
MACAddress=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff

[Link]
Name=enp2s0
WakeOnLan=off
```

10-netplan-enp2s0.network:

```
[Match]
MACAddress=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
Name=enp2s0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
DNS=10.9.8.8
Domains=lan

[DHCP]
UseMTU=true
RouteMetric=100
ClientIdentifier=mac
CriticalConnection=true
```

I though maybe it'll regenerate when I reboot the system, so I did, but the systemd config files still the same and complete ignore my custom settings. Am I doing something wrong or netplan is just a complete piece of garbage? that I should just go back to ifupdown?

Comment: It is not a complete piece of garbage, you haven't understood it very well. See https://netplan.io/reference

Comment: Run `networkctl status` to see your configurations.

Comment: maybe so. this is the first time i use netplan and yes i did went through netplan.io/reference (several times). I ran "netplan try", it didn't complain i have any errors. so why didn't it work?

Comment: and this is the out put of  "networkctl status": State: routable
       Address: 10.9.8.225 on enp2s0
                2603:xxxx::yyyy on enp2s0
                2603:xxxx::zzzz on enp2s0
                fd00:3024:1004::c16 on enp2s0
                fd00:3024:1004:0:52e5:49ff:fe63:7469 on enp2s0
                fe80::52e5:49ff:fe63:7469 on enp2s0
       Gateway: 10.9,8.8 (NETGEAR) on enp2s0
                fe80::2e30:33ff:fea0:c8db (NETGEAR) on enp2s0
           DNS: 10.9.8.8
Search Domains: lan

Comment: what is the path you have installed this netplan yaml file to on the filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like problem solved. It turns out there's an old .yaml file in /run/netplan that conflict with the one in /etc/netplan, once I deleted it, `netplan apply` works. (I never bother to check there since I rebooted the system many times and /run is mounted as tmpfs, how that .yaml file survive reboots is a mystery I guess).

Now next challenge:

How do I configure veth devices & netns in netplan?

Comment: In my opinion, this "feature" of netplan is a tremendous gotcha: ["All /{lib,etc,run}/netplan/*.yaml are considered. ... A file in /run/netplan completely shadows..."](https://netplan.io/reference#general-structure)

Comment: `/run` contains run-time variable data. This directory is created dynamically each time the system is rebooted, which means `/run/netplan/*.yaml` will reappear. 
Ref: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)

Answer (score 0):

netplan system-generated files under `/run/netplan` override your configuration under `/etc/netplan`. Your modifications to `/run` will not survive reboots.

From the [netplan FAQ](https://netplan.io/faq#hierarchy-of-configuration-files):

> Alphabetically later files, no matter what directory in, will amend
>   keys if the key does not already exist and override previous keys if
>   they do.

To ensure that your configuration takes precedence, rename your files under `/etc/netplan` to place them lexically after `enp2s0.yaml`, e.g. `zz-enp2s0.yaml`.